# How plot the 3d Cayley graph of $F_3$?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

Im new to mathematica and I would like to do the Cayley graph of a free group of three generators $F(a,b,c)$, such like this [image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Before making the 3D image of $F(a,b,c)$, let's warm up by making 2D images of $F(a,b)$ as shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group).

Define

```
f2[maxWordLength_] := 
 Module[{e, a, b, s, t, edgeLengths, newEdges, grow, 
         renderEdge, show, initialEdges, graph},

  e = {0, 0};
  a = {1, 0};
  b = {0, 1};
  
  s = {a, b};
  t = Join[s, -s];
  
  edgeLengths = Table[1/2^(n - 1), {n, 1, maxWordLength}];
  
  newEdges[{p1_, p2_}, len_] := Module[{new, back},
    new = Map[{p2, p2 + len #} &, t];
    back = {p2, p2 + len Normalize[p1 - p2]};
    DeleteCases[new, back]
    ];
  
  grow[{allEdges_, latestEdges_}, level_] := Module[{new},
    new = Map[newEdges[#, edgeLengths[[level]]] &, latestEdges];
    new = Flatten[new, 1];
    {Join[allEdges, new], new}
    ];
  
  renderEdge[{p1_, p2_}] := {Point[p1], Line[{p1, p2}], Point[p2]};
  show[graph_] := 
   Graphics[{PointSize -> 1/64, Map[renderEdge, First[graph]]}];
  
  initialEdges = Map[edgeLengths[[1]] {e, #} &, t];
  graph = {initialEdges, initialEdges};
  Do[graph = grow[graph, n], {n, 2, maxWordLength}];
  show[graph]
]
```

and then execute

```
Table[f2[n], {n, 1, 4}]
```

to get

[image]

Here is an explanation of this code:

A group element in $F(a,b)$ looks like, say, $abaab^{-1}$. Such group elements are called "words" and $a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}$ are called "letters".

A "vertex" is a 3D point in the graph representing a word.

An "edge" is a line in the graph, representing a connection of two vertices. Vertices are connected if the longer is produced from the shorter by the addition of one "letter" to the word. For example, $ab$ is connected to $aba$, $aba^{-1}$, and $abb$; $abb^{-1}$ doesn't count because this is just $a$.

`f2[n]` renders the graph of $F(a,b)$ for words as long as $n$ letters.

`e` is the 3D location of the identity vertex; `a` and `b` are the directions in the graph for the two generators of the group.

`s` is the set of generators; `t` is the set of letters (i.e., generators and their inverses).

`edgeLengths` are the lengths of the edges for each stage of growth. They have to get shorter to prevent the vertices from overlapping and making the graph hard to visualize. Here we choose edge lengths of $1, \frac12, \frac14, \frac18$, etc. for successive edges from the origin to a vertex. For example, the word $aba^{-1}$ will be at the vertex $(0,0)+1(1,0)+\frac12(0,1)+\frac14(-1,0) = (\frac34,\frac12)$.

`initialEdges` is the first stage of the graph, with the four edges $ea$, $eb$, $ea^{-1}$, and $eb^{-1}$, each of length 1.

The graph grows in stages, sprouting new edges from the latest edges. Thus the data for `graph` is two lists: the first is all edges and the second is the latest edges.

The `grow[]` function grows the graph by one more stage by calling `newEdges[]` on each of the latest edges. The new edges are added to the list of all edges, and the new edges become the latest edges for the next stage.

The `newEdges[]` function produces new edges from a single edge by applying all the letters. However, "going back where we came from" isn't allowed; the `DeleteCases` takes care of this.

Now we can generalize this to $F(a,b,c)$ in 3D. Define

```
f3[maxWordLength_] := 
 Module[{e, a, b, c, s, t, edgeLengths, newEdges, grow, 
         renderEdge, show, initialEdges, graph},
  e = {0, 0, 0};
  a = {1, 0, 0};
  b = {0, 1, 0};
  c = {0, 0, 1};
  
  s = {a, b, c};
  t = Join[s, -s];
  
  edgeLengths = Table[3/2^(n + 1), {n, 1, maxWordLength}];
  
  newEdges[{p1_, p2_}, len_] := Module[{new, back},
    new = Map[{p2, p2 + len #} &, t];
    back = {p2, p2 + len Normalize[p1 - p2]};
    DeleteCases[new, back]
    ];
  
  grow[{allEdges_, latestEdges_}, level_] := Module[{new},
    new = Map[newEdges[#, edgeLengths[[level]]] &, latestEdges];
    new = Flatten[new, 1];
    {Join[allEdges, new], new}
    ];
  
  renderEdge[{p1_, p2_}] := Module[{level},
    level = Position[edgeLengths, EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]][[1, 1]];
    {Cube[p1, 1/2^(level - 1)], Cube[p2, 1/2^level]}
    ];
  show[graph_] := 
   Graphics3D[Map[renderEdge, First[graph]], ImageSize -> Large];
  
  initialEdges = Map[edgeLengths[[1]] {e, #} &, t];
  graph = {initialEdges, initialEdges};
  Do[graph = grow[graph, n], {n, 2, maxWordLength}];
  show[graph]
]
```

and then execute

```
Table[f3[n], {n, 1, 4}]
```

to get the following graphs using the cubical style of rendering that you asked for:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

A few comments on the changes between `f2[]` and `f3[]`:

There is now a third generator `c`, and `e`, `a`, `b`, and `c` are three-dimensional.

Vertices are now rendered as cubes rather than points, and the cubes are butted up against each other so no edges are visible. The cubes must decrease in size so as not to overlap; we use cubes of size $1, \frac12, \frac14, \frac18$, etc. The `edgeLengths` (the distance between the centers of the cubes) has been appropriately adjusted.

If you are just starting to use *Mathematica*, this project may be more complex than you can currently handle. I've tried to write the code in a simple and straightforward way. *Mathematica* experts probably won't find it particularly elegant. This is my first answer on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange and congratulations for a very detailed first answer! :) Just a small (not very important) observation – the 3D model in the OP's question seems somehow more "loose" and "airy" than your final image. I think it is because they used cuboids instead of cubes :)

Comment: @Domen Thanks, and yes regarding cuboid vs. cubes. I wasn’t sure exactly what cuboids that image was using, so i went with cubes. The OP said “like this” so I felt that I had a bit of freedom.